# Как использовать колонку из запросa как фильтр в другом запросе?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

В заголовке смысл вопроса возможно непонятен, попробую объяснить.

Скажем, есть таблица `SOURCE_TABLE` с одной колонкой, которая выглядит вот так:

```
Filter 
------------------|
Name='John' 
Surname = 'Smith' 
Age = '25'
```

Хочу использовать эту таблицу как фильтр. Что-то вроде этого:

```
SELECT * FROM TARGET_TABLE WHERE (SELECT FILTER FROM SOURCE_TABLE)
```

Но честно говоря, не мог понять, как это сделать.

Знаете ли кто-то, как можно использовать колонку в качестве источника фильтров?

Пробовал с `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`. Но есть проблема - это должно быть динамически по отношению к конечному результату, и хочется вывести результат запроса в конце.

```
DECLARE 
    my_filter VARCHAR2(100); 
    my_query VARCHAR2(500); 
BEGIN 
    my_query := 'SELECT FILTER FROM SOURCE_TABLE WHERE ROWNUM=1'; 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE my_query INTO my_filter; 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT * FROM TARGET_TABLE WHERE '||my_filter; 
END;
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Can I use a query by itself as a filter in pl/sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63950437) от участника [@eoeroglu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8050868/eoeroglu)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/63950437

Answer (score 2):

Допустим, есть эти двe таблицы с данными:

```
create table target_table (name varchar2 (16), surname varchar2(16));
insert all 
    into target_table values ('John', 'Doe')
    into target_table values ('Ann', 'Smith')
    into target_table values ('Steven', 'Feuerstein')
    into target_table values ('Steven', 'King')
select * from dual
/
create table source_table (filter varchar2 (32))
/
insert all
    into source_table values (q'[name='John']') 
    into source_table values (q'[name='Ann']')
    into source_table values (q'[name='Steven' and surname='King']')
    into source_table values (q'[surname='Feuerstein']')
select *from dual
/
```

Можно использовать функции [XMLTABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/XMLTABLE.html#GUID-C4A32C58-33E5-4CF1-A1FE-039550D3ECFA) и [DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXMLTYPE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_XMLGEN.html#GUID-8128DE5B-14CF-4D47-905B-733A49045772) и получить желаемый результат динамически:

```
select t.*, s.filter 
from source_table s, xmlTable (
    upper ('/rowset/row')
    passing dbms_xmlgen.getXMLtype (
        'select * from target_table where '||s.filter)
    columns 
        name    varchar2 (16) path 'NAME',
        surname varchar2 (16) path 'SURNAME') t
```

Результат:

```
NAME             SURNAME          FILTER                          
---------------- ---------------- --------------------------------
John             Doe              name='John'                     
Ann              Smith            name='Ann'                      
Steven           King             name='Steven' and surname='King'
Steven           Feuerstein       surname='Feuerstein'
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63952827) от участника [@Sayan Malakshinov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/429100/sayan-malakshinov)</sub>